# OpenServer: Symfony возвращает text/plain вместо text/javascript

Tags: javascript, symfony, openserver

В проекте на Symfony в папке public/ положил файлы js и css, но в браузере ( тестировал в `mozilla`) при подключении файла выходит ошибка `Сценарий из «http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js» был загружен, хотя его MIME-тип («text/plain») не является допустимым для JavaScript.` И `JS` соответственно не работает.

Код подключения скрипта:

`<script src="{{ asset('static/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Локальный сервер `OpenServer` вместе с `symfony.exe`, `php: 7.3.2`

Comment: А остальные файлы js работают?

Comment: @ИльгамКаримов Нет у всех JS такое поведение.

Comment: в опенсервере создайте отдельный домен и проверьте работу скриптов, если все так же то переустановите сервер удалив старую папку с установкой.
Если с другим хостом все нормально то переустанавливайте симфони.

Вообще сервер решает какой файл чему соответствует, если не передать явно другие заголовки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если мы говорим про статику, то ее загрузка, строго говоря, не имеет (или скорее не долджна иметь) к Symfony ни какого отношения. Статику должен отдавать веб в шаблоне же (в вашем примере `<script src="{{ asset('static/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>` ) создаются лишь правильные ссылки.

Я не очень силен в разработке в Win среде, однако в предполагаю что тут вопрос в корректной настройке OpenServer чтобы он отдавал статику с корректными mime-type.

Я так понимаю что openserver работает с Apache,
беглое гугленье подсказывает проверить наличие вот такой конфигурации.

```
<Files "*.js">
    ForceType text/javascript
</Files>
```

Посмотрите вот тут  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935119/set-my-js-mime-type-to-text-javascript  там есть еще второй ответ, который вам возможно поможет.

Comment: Данный метод пробовал, не помогло, но спасибо за ответ. Решил проблему радикально, поднял виртуальную машину Linux и работаю на ней. P.S. В Linux всё хорошо.

Comment: @АлексейСемянников посмотрите в сторону docker, очень удобный инструмент